# Remove Rows That Only Contain One Category - Pandas - Python

Tags: pandas

How do I remove rows that contain only one category without removing it specifically, (by `df.person`)?

**EDIT:** Only `df.person` that has specifically all 'not fun' for every row must be removed.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'category': ['fun','fun','fun', 'not fun','not fun','not fun', 'fun', 'not fun','not fun'],
                   'person': ['Meagan', 'Meagan', 'Meagan', 'Caitlin', 'Caitlin', 'Caitlin', 'Steve', 'Steve','Steve']})
print(df)

      category   person
0      fun   Meagan
1      fun   Meagan
2      fun   Meagan
3  not fun  Caitlin
4  not fun  Caitlin
5  not fun  Caitlin
6      fun    Steve
7  not fun    Steve
8  not fun    Steve
```

**EDIT:** Desired dataframe below. I want to remove Caitlin because she is not fun all the time. If I remove any person that is not fun occasionally, Ill remove steve and I dont want to do that. I cant remove one group of fun, because both Meagan and Caitlin will be removed.

```
category    person
0   fun     Meagan
1   fun     Meagan
2   fun     Meagan
6   fun     Steve
7  not fun  Steve
8  not fun  Steve
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First we create a `boolean array` for all rows with `not fun`.

Then we check with `Groupby.transform(all)` with groups have `all not fun` and drop these groups:

```
df['m'] = df['category'].eq('not fun')
df[~df.groupby('person')['m'].transform('all')].drop(columns='m')

  category  person
0      fun  Meagan
1      fun  Meagan
2      fun  Meagan
6      fun   Steve
7  not fun   Steve
8  not fun   Steve
```

Comment: Hi Erfan, thank you for the input. I had to adjust the problem slightly, where I cannot use nunique in the nest. Any help would be appreciated.